# Joining Two Tables in MySQL with diff column name

Tags: mysql, join

I'm not very good at joining tables in mysql and I'm still learning,
So I wanted to ask, when joining two tables....

I have 2 tables
So for the first table I want to join the 2 of its columns (id & path) on the second table.

But on the second table there's no column name id and path, there is a column name pathid & value. The field of the pathid column is the same as the id.

it looks like this.

first table

```
| id | path        | 
---------------------
|  1 | country/usa |     
|  2 | country/jpn |    
|  3 | country/kor |
```

second table

```
| pathid | value  |
-------------------
|  3     | 500    |    
|  1     | 10000  |    
|  2     | 2000   |
```

So on the first table, it indicates that for usa the id is 1, japan is 2, korea is 3.
And on the table it says that for pathid no. 3 ( which is the id for korea) the value is 500 and so on with the others.

I want it to look like this. So then the path will be joined on the second table on its corresponding value. How can I do this on mysql? Thank You

Desired Result

```
| id | path         | value  |
------------------------------
|  1 | country/usa  | 10000  |    
|  2 | country/jpn  | 2000   |    
|  3 | country/kor  | 500    |
```

Comment: `SELECT...FROM firstTB a INNER JOIN  secondTB b ON a.id = b.pathID` -- simple join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can join on the columns irrespective of the column name as long as the data type match.

```
SELECT id, path, value
FROM firstTable, secondTable
WHERE id = pathid
```

If you have same column names on both tables then you need to qualify the name using alias. Say the column names for `id` were same on both tables then whenever you use `id` you should mention which table you are referring to. other wise it will complain about the ambiguity.

```
SELECT s.id, path, value
FROM firstTable f, secondTable s
WHERE f.id = s.pathid
```

Note that I ommited `s.` on other columns in select, it will work as long as the second table doesn't have columns with same name.

Comment: Thanks Lobo! The first statement is just what I needed! Thanks! :D

Comment: welcome. spend some time understanding the different types of joins. well worth the time I promise.

Comment: One more thing, on the path since the path is like country/usa, is there a way where i can output just the usa?

Comment: Yes, you have to use `substring(path,9)`. Refer string functions in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html)